# Puppet include all repositories before installing package

Tags: postgresql, puppet, redhat, yum

i'm trying to install postgresql from puppetlabs package, but i need that will use my own package on my own repository.
So i'm able to specify which package should install, which service name will have and so on.
Then  i'm going to erase all repos from the server and let puppet install all repos.
That's what i think things should works:

```
node name { 
 include repos::internal::blabla
 class {'database':
 someparameters=>somevalue,
}
```

So this code in my mind should install all repos before the database, but even if i use require repos::...... isn't working anyway.
That's what i got:

```
Debug: Prefetching yum resources for package
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm --version'
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -qa --nosignature --nodigest --qf '%{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n''
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q postgresql91 --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
Debug: Executing '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list postgresql91'
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list postgresql91' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
Error: /Stage[main]/Postgresql::Client/Package[postgresql-client]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list postgresql91' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -q postgresql91-server --nosignature --nodigest --qf %{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}\n'
Debug: Executing '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list postgresql91-server'
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list postgresql91-server' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
Error: /Stage[main]/Postgresql::Server::Install/Package[postgresql-server]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list postgresql91-server' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
Debug: Prefetching inifile resources for yumrepo
Notice: /Stage[main]/Repos::Internal::Integration/Yumrepo[official-repository]/ensure: created
Info: changing mode of /etc/yum.repos.d/official-repository.repo from 600 to 644
Debug: /Stage[main]/Repos::Internal::Integration/Yumrepo[official-repository]: The container Class[Repos::Internal::Integration] will propagate my refresh event
Notice: /Stage[main]/Repos::Internal::Integration/Yumrepo[commonfor91]/ensure: created
Info: changing mode of /etc/yum.repos.d/commonfor91.repo from 600 to 644
Debug: /Stage[main]/Repos::Internal::Integration/Yumrepo[commonfor91]: The container Class[Repos::Internal::Integration] will propagate my refresh event
Notice: /Stage[main]/Repos::Internal::Integration/Yumrepo[epel-6]/ensure: created
Info: changing mode of /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-6.repo from 600 to 644
Debug: /Stage[main]/Repos::Internal::Integration/Yumrepo[epel-6]: The container Class[Repos::Internal::Integration] will propagate my refresh event
```

What's wrong? Thanks in advance.
I'm using puppet 3.7.3 on redhat.

Comment: which one is your own package? is it `repos::internal::blabla`?

Comment: nope, that's is just a class that contains yumrepos. postgresql91 package is in one of the repo that is specified in repos::internal::blabla
the class database will use puppetlabs/postgresql module, i just want to be sure that all repos exist before listing package.

Comment: Have you tried adding the relation between class database and repos::internal::blabla ? 
Consider adding: require     => Class['Repos::Internal::Blabla'] , to class 'database'.

Comment: @kkamilpl yes inside the database.pp it's working, but i want to avoid that. I want that the node will create yumrepo before everything else.
Maybe inside repos::internal::blabla i have to specify something else insead only "yumrepo{...} yumrepo{...}" 
If i wrote: 
node name1 {
require repos::internal::blabla
class {'database':}
}
I guess that all stuff in repos::...::... should be applied before database. Am i wrong?

Comment: According to docs https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#the-require-function, changing include repos::internal::blabla to require repos::internal::blabla should resolve you issue, because "The require function declares a class and causes it to become a dependency of the surrounding container". If it will not be working, I have no other ideas.

Comment: @kkamilpl maybe is 3.7.3 puppet version bugged, or as postgresql module using anchor maybe override node order. Or maybe require class isn't working inside a node declaration... Anyway neither with require that stuff is working. Repos are created ony AFTER prefetching resources like i wrote in the main question, and my yum.repos.d is empty.

Comment: @kkamilpl if used in `node` context, this is bound to fail, because making something a dependency of the whole node makes no sense.

Comment: @FelixFrank I will disagree. Cenoxdj said: "I want that the node will create yumrepo before everything else.", and require function exactly does it. Require will ensure that "repos::internal::blabla" will be included to node and it will execute  repos::internal::blabla code before executing code in node.

Comment: @kkamilpl that seems to be true. Testable via `puppet apply -e 'node default { require all notify { "it works": } } class all { file { "/this/path/is/invalid": ensure => file } }'`. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between the classes is built, but this is insufficient, because relationships will not typically cross class include boundaries.

> Error: /Stage[main]/Postgresql::Server::Install/Package[postgresql-server]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list postgresql91-server' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list

Please note that this `package` is dcalred by `Class[postgresql::server::install]` and not `Class['database']`. The former is directly or indirectly included by the latter. But ordering rules will not applied to included classes (it would be very hurtful to complex manifests if this were the case).

To make the dependencies work at least in the scope of your own modules, try and use

```
contain postgresql
```

in your `database` module instead of

```
include postgresql
```

If you need to pass parameters to the `postgresql` module, consider doing this through [Hiera](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup).

---

**Original answer** before update on 2015-01-02.

There is a variety of ways to express what you want. One of the most straight forward ones:

```
Yumrepo<| |> -> Class['database']
```

Note that this will realize any virtual `yumrepo` resources you might be using. If this is unacceptable to you, you can get more selective.

```
Class['repos::internal::blabla'] -> Class['database']
```

The basis of this is the [chaining](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#chaining-arrows) operator. It should get you going in some way like those depicted above.

Comment: I already propose that solution "Have you tried adding the relation between class database and repos::internal::blabla ? Consider adding: require => Class['Repos::Internal::Blabla'] , to class 'database'."

Comment: Yes. Isn't really what i wanted, but better than nothing. My problem was that require or include inside the node don't create repos before the package, so it fails. I need to specific Yumrepo in a require parameter of the package i install. But what i really wanted was have all repo installed before anything else.

Comment: Well, the sledge hammer for that is `Yumrepo<| |> -> Package<| |>`. YMMV.